# How to display histogram of image on CimgDisplay window

Tags: cimg

I am using Cimg library

I have a image: `CImg image;`

And `CImgDisplay main_disp;`

I want to display histogram of `image` on main_`disp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the CImg documentation:
http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/index.html

And, here's some code that computes a histogram from an image and displays it on a pre-existing display:

```
// create display and image
CImg< float > image;
CImgDisplay< float > main_disp;

// do some stuff to populate image ...

// compute the histogram
const CImg< float > histogram = img.histogram( numberOfBins );

// display histogram on display
main_disp.display( histogram );

// wait until display is closed
while ( !main_disp.is_closed() ) { main_disp.wait(); }
```